# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am new to MVC4, I want to implement WebGrid, When retrieving data for model.activity its working fine. For clarification i am combining two tables to get data.

Here its showing error like this
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List**

Please help me to solve this problem. thanks in advance

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Tbl_Activity> activity;
    public List<Tbl_Clarification> clarification;
}

  public class ClarificationEntities
{
    public int ClrNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DailyReportID { get; set; }
    public string ReportingMgrComment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string StaffComment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am adding data to the model to display in WebGrid

```
 MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
 model.activity = db.Tbl_Activity.Where(x => x.DailyReportID == driD).ToList();
 model.clarification = (from c in db.Tbl_Clarification
                        join u in db.Tbl_Users on c.CreatedBy equals u.CreatedBy
                        where c.DailyReportID == did
                        select new ClarificationEntities
                         {
                           ClrNo = c.ClrNo,     
                           ReportingMgrComment = c.ReportingMgrComment,
                           StaffComment = c.StaffComment,
                           DailyReportID=c.DailyReportID,
                           Name=u.Name
                          }).ToList();
  return View(model);
```

Comment: Your `model.clarification` is of type `List<Tbl_Clarification>` but you are fetching `List<ClarificationEntities>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyViewModel` has the wrong type for the `clarification` field...

try the following instead

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Tbl_Activity> activity;
    public List<ClarificationEntities> clarification;
}
```